# My api code retrieves an empty data array from mongodb while the code works well on mongodb playground

Tags: javascript, mongodb, api

My mongodb database includes a collection of users and each user has an array of shops and each shop has an array of products. Here is a simplified version of my collection structure:

```
[
    {
        "_id": "60e66b70da2439232e330415",
        "name": "User1 Name",
        "shops": [
            {
                "_id": "60e7c9e2be0d8f03544a03b8",
                "shopName": "User1 Shop1 Name",
                "products": [
                    {
                        "_id": "60e9e9e8105d6021a2e91535",
                        "title": "User1 Shop1 Product1 Title"
                    },
                    {
                        "_id": "60e9f4a0105d6021a2e91536",
                        "title": "User1 Shop1 Product2 Title"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "_id": "60e8e8c00f3986577cb968c9",
                "shopName": "User1 Shop2 Name",
                "products": [
                    {
                        "_id": "60e9f4fe105d6021a2e91537",
                        "title": "User1 Shop2 Product1 Title"
                    },
                    {
                        "_id": "60e9f515105d6021a2e91538",
                        "title": "User1 Shop2 Product2 Title"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "_id": "60e66b93da2439232e330416",
        "name": "User2 Name",
        "shops": [
            {
                "_id": "60e69698e76cad44e49e1fc8",
                "shopName": "User2 Shop1 Name",
                "products": [
                    {
                        "_id": "60e9f588105d6021a2e91539",
                        "title": "User2 Shop1 Product1 Title"
                    },
                    {
                        "_id": "60e9f59c105d6021a2e9153a",
                        "title": "User2 Shop1 Product2 Title"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "_id": "60e902b441e9df63c7fbcb49",
                "shopName": "User2 Shop2 Name",
                "products": [
                    {
                        "_id": "60e9f5c9105d6021a2e9153b",
                        "title": "User2 Shop2 Product1 Title"
                    },
                    {
                        "_id": "60e9f5de105d6021a2e9153c",
                        "title": "User2 Shop2 Product2 Title"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

I have an api endpoint like `.../api/products/60e9f5de105d6021a2e9153c`. This endpoint includes a parameter which is a productId. I have the following two codes to retrieve the product data from my mongodb collection, but the retrieved array is empty.

My endpoint code:

```
app.get("/api/products/:productId", (req,res)=>{
    let productId = req.params.productId;
    myData.getProductByProductId(productId)
    .then(products => res.json(products))
    .catch(err => res.json({"message": err}));
});
```

My DataService code:

```
getProductByProductId: function (productId) {
            return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                User.aggregate([
                    {
                      $match: {
                        "shops.products._id": productId
                      }
                    },
                    {
                      "$unwind": "$shops"
                    },
                    {
                      "$unwind": "$shops.products"
                    },
                    {
                      $match: {
                        "shops.products._id": productId
                      }
                    },
                    {
                      $project: {
                        "_id": "$shops.products._id",
                        "title": "$shops.products.title"
                      }
                    }
                  ])
                .exec().then(products => {
                    resolve(products)
                }).catch(err => {
                    reject(err);
                });
            });
        }
```

The aggregate code works well in [this playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/kZsx8CC4d3P) but in my web app code retrieves an empty array.

Comment: are you using mongoosh?

Comment: @RajdeepDebnath Yes I am using Mongoose.

Comment: Please try `User.aggregate(..).then(successCallback);` Remove the exec()

Comment: Thanks @RajdeepDebnath. It gives me this output now:

{
    "message": {}
}

Comment: ok, that means error, you can try console logging `then(products => {
                    console.log(products)
                }).catch(err => {
                    console.log(err);
                })`

Comment: @RajdeepDebnath It gives only an empty array: []

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235153/discussion-between-rajdeep-debnath-and-omid).

Comment: @RajdeepDebnath
Thank you so much for spending so much time on chat to debug my code and resolve the issue. I am waiting for you to insert the final solution here so that I can upvote it. Thank you so much. That was incredible help man.

Comment: @RajdeepDebnath I also posted another issue related to the same api code. It is highly appreciated if you could kindly take a look at your convenience. Thank you so much. Here is the link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68477725/updating-and-element-of-a-2nd-level-nested-array-in-api-code-for-mongodb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the casting of the ObjectId seemed to be the issue. We need to use `mongoose.Types.ObjectId`

The API code will looks like this

```
getProductByProductId: function (productId) {
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  User.aggregate([
  {
  $match: {
    "shops.products._id": mongoose.Types.ObjectId(productId)
  }
  },
  {
    "$unwind": "$shops"
  },
  {
    "$unwind": "$shops.products"
  },
  {
    $match: {
    "shops.products._id": mongoose.Types.ObjectId(productId)
  }
  },
  {
  $project: {
  "_id": "$shops.products._id",
  "title": "$shops.products.title"
  }
}
])
.then(products => {
resolve(products)
}).catch(err => {
reject(err);
});
});
}
```